# Google Actions + Webhook + GoogleSheets integration

Tags: node.js, webhooks, google-assistant-sdk

Im trying to build what I thought would be a simple call and response scenario with Google Actions. I'm trying to ask google actions a question and behind the scenes a webhook gets invoked which pulls a single value from a google sheet and the google assistant reads it out.

My programming experience is solely in SQL and even that is not strong so apologies if this is a complete shambles. I've managed to set up the google actions scenes via the gui but the webhook call is where I'm falling short. I've posted where I have got to today via a number of google searches.

I assume this is super easy but with my no coding experience I'm learning the basics in node.js, google actions together, I just wanted to get an understanding if I'm going in th right direction or if I'm completely off the mark.

**UPDATE:08/03:**- Where I've got to with the below is the handle gets called when the google intent happens and that seems to work fine. Then I can see in the console.log that the axios.get is reaching the API and pulling the data. So the with the conv.add I was hoping that by putting response it would take whats in the axios response and call that out as speech but it doesnt seem to work.

I think where I'm getting stuck is what do I do with the response from the axios.get to turn it into something google actions can respond in speech?

```
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = conversation({debug: true});

app.handle('YTDget', conv => {

  axios.get ('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/u1yid5jisv40g')
    .then (response => {
      console.log (response);
    });

  conv.add(response);

});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Question: what's the function you're passing into `app.handle(...)` supposed to do? Because as written, it does nothing: it only declares two functions, never calls them, and exits. Move those functions out so they get declared at the same level as `app`, and write a new `app.handle` function that actually does something with `conv`? Also, youtube links are generally not a good link, because you're asking people for help, and they expect [all the details in your post](/help/how-to-ask): they shouldn't have to sit through a video before they can do that.

Comment: I'm still seeing the same code as before (the post does not show an edit by you), where you handler ultimately "does nothing" (it does a bunch of things, but those things don't actually lead to any code execution, so they're effectively just noop - code that take up cpu cycles, but don't effect anything)

Comment: sorry @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - i just edited the actual post itself with an 08/03 update. You responded before I could correct my error haha. Super fast :)

Comment: You should be returning `axios.get` and put `conv.add` within the `then` block

Comment: @cassidyshark remember that your new code does something _very different_, so: does your question still apply does it need rewriting based on what the new code behaviour is? Remember that you're not just asking for yourself, but for every future visitor to SO too, so don't add an "edit" heading, rewrite the post to reflect your current problem, if there is one =)

Comment: Having said that: note that proper code indentation can help you discover problems that are otherwise very hard to spot: with proper indentation (which every code editor can do for you, although you might need to install a code formatter - for JS, I recommend installing `prettier`) we can see that the `conv.add(response);` line is not in the right place.